# Git path is not accepted while upgrading from capistrano v2 to v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano, capistrano3

I have git in my app path. Already I am using capistrano 2 to deploy the same app. It accepts my git path. Through that I can do all operations(git pull, push). But why my git path is not accepted with capistrano 3 for the same app?

```
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    /usr/bin/env: 
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    git
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [c5891dcc]    
DEBUG [c5891dcc] Finished in 0.664 seconds with exit status 127 (failed).
```

Comment: It looks like this isn't looking for `git` on your path directly, but rather it's trying to run `/usr/bin/env git`. Do you have `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: @Chris- yeah. I have /usr/bin/env.

Comment: And, for instance, `/usr/bin/env git --version` works?

Comment: @Chris - this gives me git version 1.7.9.5

Comment: I've had similar issue with v3, all I had to done was to reinstall git (that was the fastest way I found), I know that's not a true anwer, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: @zrl3dx - Let me try and tell you. thanks

Comment: @zrl3dx - after reinstalling git I am getting the same error